# Serialize Form GetJSON returns null model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, serialization, model-binding

I have a form I am trying to send in a GetJSON call.  When I get to the Controller the model that si tied to the view is a null vlaue.  I have had issues before dealign with returning data when I woudl get an empy object but never a null value.  Below is the code I am using to send the form

```
  var cqvdata = $("form").serialize();

  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetEmailByAdvanced", "CustomerEmails")', { cqv: cqvdata }, function (contacts) {
       var emails = "";
       $.each(contacts, function (index, contact) {
           $('#BCCText').tagit('createTag', contact.Email)
       });

       return false;
   });
```

Below is what I have on the controller side

```
 public JsonResult GetEmailByAdvanced(MassEmailViewModel cqv)
 {


 }
```

Here is what I get for results if I turn my argument into a string

```
"EmailFromAddressID=1&ToAddresses=&CCAddresses=bclairmont%40harr.com&BCCAddresses=adunn%40harr.com&Subject=&Body="
```

Below is the MassEmailViewModelClass and all sub classes

```
public class MassEmailViewModel
{
    public MassEmailViewModel()
    {
        ComplexQuery = new CustomerQueryViewModel();
    }

    public int EmailFromAddressID { get; set; }

    public CustomerQueryViewModel ComplexQuery { get; set; }

    public string ToAddresses { get; set; }
    public string CCAddresses { get; set; }
    public string BCCAddresses { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

}

 public class CustomerQueryViewModel
{
    public CustomerQueryViewModel()
    {
        Products = new List<CustomerProductQueryProduct>();
        Details = new List<CustomerQueryDetail>();
    }

    public Boolean IncludeOnAll { get; set; }
    public Boolean ExcludeOnAll { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerProductQueryProduct> Products { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerQueryDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerProductQueryProduct
{
    public CustomerProductQueryProduct()
    {
        ProductDetails = new List<CustomerProductQueryProductDetail>();
        ProductVersions = new List<ProductVersion>();
    }

    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public Boolean Exclude { get; set; }
    public Boolean Include { get; set; }
    public int VersiondID { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerProductQueryProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    public List<ProductVersion> ProductVersions { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerProductQueryProductDetail
{
    public ProductTypeDetail ProductDetail { get; set; }
    public Boolean Exclude { get; set; }
    public Boolean Include { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerQueryDetail
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Boolean Exclude { get; set; }
    public Boolean Include { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

The only thing not being returned is my ComplexQuery in the serialize because I am using a JQuery dialog so it takes those elements out of the form.  I woudl think I woudl get a MassEmaikViewModel with all the vlaues but ComplexQuery and have a null for that but I just get a null as iff the argument never even got initialized.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

One other thing and I don't know if this will help give anyone any insight or not but I can post from the form and have the MassEmailViewModel as the argument in the post and it works fine filling out all the values except for ComplexQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after a ton of trial and error.  It seems like GetJSON can't handle passing the data.  What I did to correctly get information was to change to an AJAX get call.  I will post the code below

```
 $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetEmailByAdvanced", "CustomerEmails")',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: cqvdata,
                            success: function (data) {
                                //called when successful
                                var emails = "";
                                $.each(contacts, function (index, contact) {
                                    $('#BCCText').tagit('createTag', contact.Email)
                                });

                                return false;
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                //called when there is an error
                                //console.log(e.message);
                            }
                        });
```

I used the exact data I had in the GetJSON.  In fact I commented out the GetJSON and just put this in below it and I got my model filled in on the controller side.